# Swift 'NSArray?' does not have member named 'count'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty sure `.count` returns the length of an array but for some reason when I used it, it threw a weird error.

Heres my code:

```
let dataFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(RopeDataFile, ofType: nil)
let ropes = NSArray(contentsOfFile: dataFile!);

for i in 0..<ropes.count {
}
```

`RopeDataFile` is a constant of a property list that I made earlier.

For some reason it gives this error on `ropes.count`,

> 'NSArray?' does not have member named 'count'.

I'm new to swift and sorry if the problem is really simple.

Comment: post the error you get

Comment: The clue is the question mark, by the way. Pay attention to those question marks in your error messages; they indicate that you're dealing with an Optional. "NSArray" has a count method; "NSArray?" doesn't; you need to unwrap the Optional somehow before you start accessing methods of the NSArray inside it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSArray(contentsOfFile: dataFile!)` returns an **optional** array. So you have to use like

```
ropes?.count
```

Or you can unwrap the `ropes` array first

```
if let array = ropes{
       for i in 0..< array.count {
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ropes!.count
```

use `!`

```
NSArray(contentsOfFile: dataFile!) return an optional array
```

Comment: Bear in mind that if loading the array from the file failed, this will cause a runtime error (that's *why* NSArray(contentsOfFile:) is an optional initialiser; it's possible for the array not to be created if the file's in the wrong format, or doesn't exist, etc.)